# Validate Wordpress Media Attachment Field on Selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

We are extending/modifying the Media uploader UI (wp.media frame) to allow for basic validation of certain metadata fields of the media file before being inserted into the post. The aim is to force editors to always add a credit to any photo after uploading or selecting.

The validator shows a warning and hides the select button if no data is found in the media_credit field and also displays a checkbox to allows editors to override this rule if that's what they really want:

[image]

We are using `wp.media` extender to extend and add the validation functionality on the frame's selection.single event since this fires whenever an image is selected from the library or when uploaded and then selected automatically. We access the attachment data in this event, extract the attachment.id and target the media_credit field textbox (`<input type="text" class="text" id="attachments-256993-media_credit" name="attachments[256993][media_credit]" value="">`) using this id The problem we are facing is that the attachment data within this event doesn't contain id value when this event is triggered for a just uploaded image rather than just selecting from the library.

attachment.id shows up as undefined in this case but after a few seconds, the data does show up. But the code cannot wait for the attachment data to be refreshed (since its not aync) and hence gets only undefined.

[image]

**Current Patch:** I added a setTimeout handler to delay the processing by an arbitrary time (2s) and this works - but of course this is not usable since the delay is sometimes not enough for larger files that take longer than 2s to upload and get processed.

Ideally we need a callback function that is called when the image is fully processed and the attachment.id is available where we can drop our validation code in, rather than building workarounds using timeouts.

Here's the current handler code:

```
( function( $ ) {
    var media_credit = '';
    var selection    = '';
    if ( wp.media ) {

        wp.media.view.Modal.prototype.on( "open", function() {
            if ( typeof wp.media.frame.state() !== 'undefined' ) {
                selection = wp.media.frame.state().get('selection')
            } else if ( typeof wp.media.featuredImage.frame().state('featured-image') !== 'undefined' ) {
                selection = wp.media.featuredImage.frame().state('featured-image').get('selection');
            }
            console.log('state', wp.media.frame.state().get('selection').first());

            if ( selection ) {
                console.log('add', selection);

                selection.on( 'selection:unsingle', function ( attachment ) {
                    console.log('unselected');
                    $('.confirm_field').remove();
                    $('.media-frame-toolbar > .media-toolbar .media-toolbar-secondary .credit-notice').remove();
                });

                selection.on( 'add', function ( attachment ) {

                    console.log('insert add', attachment);

                    var attach_id = '';
                    if (typeof attachment.id !== 'undefined' ) { // this is for selected from library
                        console.log(attachment);
                        attach_id = attachment.id;
                        console.log('attachment.id without delay', attach_id, $('#attachments-' + attach_id + '-media_credit') );
                        media_watch(attach_id);
                    } else {
                        // this is for uploaded
                        attach_id = selection.first().changed.id;
                        console.log('attachment.id with delay', attach_id, $('#attachments-' + attach_id + '-media_credit') );
                        media_watch(attach_id);
                    }

                    function media_watch(aid) {
                        // Check if credit data has value
                        let media_credit = $('#attachments-' + aid + '-media_credit').val();

                        let confirm_field = '<table class="confirm_field"><tr class="compat-field-media_confirm"><th scope="row" class="label"><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="confirmNoCredit" value="yes"></th><td class="field"><label for="confirmNoCredit"><p class="description">Confirm without credit</p></label></td></tr></table>';
                        let notice        = '<div class="credit-notice notice notice-warning notice-alt inline"><p>The selected image has no Credit value. You are advised to add proper Credit. </p></div>';

                        // Hide the select button and show warning message
                        if ( media_credit == '' || ! media_credit ) {
                            $('.media-frame-toolbar > .media-toolbar .media-toolbar-primary').hide();
                            $('.media-sidebar').append(confirm_field);
                            $('.media-frame-toolbar > .media-toolbar > .media-toolbar-secondary').html(notice);
                        } else {
                            $('.media-frame-toolbar > .media-toolbar .media-toolbar-primary').show();
                        }

                        $(document).on('change', '#attachments-' + aid + '-media_credit', function() {
                            console.log('credit value', this.value.length);
                            if(this.value.length == 0) {
                                $('.media-frame-toolbar > .media-toolbar .media-toolbar-primary').hide();
                                $('.confirm_field').remove();
                                $('.media-sidebar').append(confirm_field);
                                $('.media-frame-toolbar > .media-toolbar > .media-toolbar-secondary').html(notice);
                            } else {
                                $('.confirm_field').remove();
                                $('.media-frame-toolbar > .media-toolbar .media-toolbar-primary').show();
                                $('.media-frame-toolbar > .media-toolbar .media-toolbar-secondary .credit-notice').remove();
                            }
                        });

                        // When editor check the checkbox (this is working)
                        $(document).on('change', "#confirmNoCredit", function() {
                            console.log('checked state', this.checked );
                            if(this.checked) {
                                $('.media-frame-toolbar > .media-toolbar .media-toolbar-primary').show();
                                $('.media-frame-toolbar > .media-toolbar .media-toolbar-secondary .credit-notice').remove();
                            } else {
                                $('.media-frame-toolbar > .media-toolbar .media-toolbar-primary').hide();
                                $('.media-frame-toolbar > .media-toolbar > .media-toolbar-secondary').html(notice);
                            }
                        });
                    }

                } );
            }
        });

        // Execute this code when a Modal is closed.
        wp.media.view.Modal.prototype.on( "close", function() {
            $('.credit-notice').remove();
        });

    }
})( jQuery );
```